# Symfony2 Doctrine - two different relations between two thesame entities?

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I use Symfony 2 and Doctrine ORM

I want to create in my project a module with posts and comments to each one.

I have the entities `Profile` (which store users) and `Comments` (which obviously store comments)

I need to create two different relations between the same entities.

Firstly need to store in `Comments` entity the author of comment ( relation 1 to 1).
But secondly for every comment want to add option "like" and "dislike" which every user can use. 
I suppose that I need many to many relation between `Profile` and `Comment` entities which will store information about like/dislike action.

I have never created 2 entities with two different relations between them. Have you got any experience with that? Or maybe I am taking this problem wrong way and should act differently that I think.

Please any help or clue will by appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see a very similar example in the doctrine documentation for associations:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#association-example-entities

It's pretty easy to put this in your use case. (Attention: Untested copy&paste code incoming!)

In `Profile` you define:

```
/**
 * Bidirectional - Many users have Many liked comments (OWNING SIDE)
 *
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Comment", inversedBy="profileLikes")
 * @JoinTable(name="profile_liked_comments")
 */
private $commentsLiked;

/**
 * Bidirectional - Many users have Many liked comments (OWNING SIDE)
 *
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Comment", inversedBy="profileDislikes")
 * @JoinTable(name="profile_disliked_comments")
 */
private $commentsDisliked;

/**
 * Bidirectional - One-To-Many (INVERSE SIDE)
 *
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="author")
 */
private $commentsAuthored;
```

and in `Comment` you define:

```
/**
 * Bidirectional - Many comments are liked by many users (INVERSE SIDE)
 *
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="commentsLiked")
 */
private $profileLikes;

/**
 * Bidirectional - Many comments are disliked by many users (INVERSE SIDE)
 *
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="commentsDisliked")
 */
private $profileDislikes;

/**
 * Bidirectional - Many Comments are authored by one user (OWNING SIDE)
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profile", inversedBy="commentsAuthored")
 */
 private $author;
```

Note that I changed the relation of `Profile` to `Comment` from OneToOne to OneToMany as I assume users should be able to write more than one comment.

Comment: Thanks for answer, now I am reading whole documentation of Doctrine. Hope I wont need to ask more questions in this topic :)